# Defining a string as a variable to make code run faster

Tags: java

Suppose I have a dictionary in java and its keys are strings. I call this dictionary millions of times (in a for loop). Is it faster to define the keys names at the beginning and use these variables or is it the same as using the string itself?

```
String p = "key1"
dic.put(p,value)
```

vs

```
dic.put("key1", value)
```

If so, then why?

Comment: There's no difference between the two.

Comment: I don't think it is granted that both versions will produce identical code.  But contrary to your expectation, I think that the second way (using the variable) could actually be *slower* if the compiler cannot prove that the reference is not changed.  In contrast to this, a literal is guaranteed to never change value.  You can guide the compiler (and avoid silly bugs for yourself) by declaring the variable as `final`, though, in which case I don't expect any difference between the two codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same bytecode is generated from these two code snippets. So, it does not matter.